# How convert a SQL Server trigger into Oracle trigger?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to convert a SQL Server trigger into a Oracle trigger, this trigger is about if I sell a product and the product quantity is 0 then the sale must be cancel but the sintaxis for oracle is kind of different.

Here is the SQL Server version

```
create trigger IfQuantityIsZero on Products for update 
as 
IF (SELECT Quantity FROM INSERTED) < 0 BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('The sale can not be made, it exceeds the existing quantity of the product.',10,1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ifquantityiszero BEFORE
     UPDATE  --OR INSERT 
   ON products FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF
          :NEW.quantity < 1 --refer to the modified columns in products using :NEW.column
     THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'The sale can not be made, it exceeds the existing quantity of the product.'
          );

     END IF;
END;
/
```